# Постинг приватных фидов от имени конторы

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Здравствуйте, я хочу постить в Facebook фиды, видимые только одному пользователю от имени компании (подобно постингу на странице, только с возможностью настроек приватности). Не подскажите, есть ли в fb подобный инструмент?

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите на страницу своей "конторы" (под её логином) и попробуйте установить настройки приватности для новой записи. Так вот - их попросту нет.

Comment: Да, это я уже понял. А нет ли какой-нибудь другой сущности, решающей эту задачу?

Comment: Нет, даже сообщения нельзя посылать людям, которые вас лайкают: https://www.facebook.com/help/273376269375028/ (ну если они сами не написали)